# codeigniter email not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having the small alignment issue in my email. In my message i am manually adding the `<br>` tag. its not working.

**Code**

```
public function send_contact_email($data){
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'email@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'password',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );       
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    //$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    // message
    $message = 'you have recived a mail from a customer<br>
                Customer Name : '.$data['fullname'].
                '<br><br>Customer Email : '.$data['contact_email'].
                '<br>Customer website : '.$data['user_web'].
                '<br>message : '.$data['message'];


    // send mail
    $this->email->from('waveingress@gmail.com', 'Contact Information');
    $this->email->to('sathya@globalwavenet.com', 'info@annaiplan.com'); 
    $this->email->subject('A message from : '. $data['fullname']);
    $this->email->message($message);  
    $this->email->send();
}
```

But when i receive the mail it looks like this.

[image]

The `<br>` tag is not adding the new line. can some one help me to fix this.

Comment: You'll probably have to send actual HTML instead of text containing HTML tags. Try wrapping your text in `<html></html>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing set as html param for `emailer`, you have to set it if you want that `<br>` and other html tags will be recognized in email clients (`yahoo`, `gmail` ...)

```
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
```